Does go optimises the re-usal of a slicing operation?
I have a difficult time to figure out if a memory footprint slicing operation of a slice in Go optimised or not. It might not matter in practice, but I was just curious.
What I am doing in my code is basically slicing an already existing slice and before I return it, I want to also log it. I was curious if I call the SAME slicing operation on the base slice, if the memory footprint of it is the same. So the question if the compiler recognises that is the same array or it creates two separate pointers.
A very simple example is:
a := make([]int, 10)


log.Msgf("the subarray is: %v", a[:4])

return a[:4]

The challenge is that the result of a bare slicing operation is not eligible to print its address according to the go compiler specs. The following code would tell me the answer, if in the consecutive prints the sliced array mem adress is the same or not, but it does not work in Go:
a := make([]int, 10)
fmt.Printf("The address is: %p", a[:4]) // Not addressable
fmt.Printf("The address is: %p", a[:4])


Same array? Two separate pointers? There are no array or pointer operations when you slice an existing slice (other than copying the pointer to the underlying array into the new slice).

Yeah so I was wondering what is the mechanics when you pass a[:4] slicint to any func or printf. I assumed indeed that a new pointer is created. However, since a[:4] appears in the same scope after each other was wondering if the Go compiler optimises that and reuses the same pointer or creates two.

If you call a function, the value has to be either put on the stack or held in registers. See: https://tip.golang.org/src/cmd/compile/abi-internal . There's no pointers involved, except fmt.Printf takes any parameters, which involves putting the arguments into an interface{} which if the value has a size bigger than a pointer (like a slice) involves a pointer, probably to a copy of the slice, possibly on the heap (depending on escape analysis).


So the question if the compiler recognises that is the same array or it creates two separate pointers.

No, the Go runtime does not do that, even though you reference only a sub-slice using a[:4], the capacity of this sub slice still remains the same as the initial slice.  The remaining elements are still allocated in memory, even if they are not referenced. The backing array that holds the slice, still keeps the all the ten elements even if you intend keep only the sub slice only.
The recommended way would be to make a slice copy instead of slicing a, so that now you have two different slice headers with pointers to backing arrays holding a and b, the former of which can be GC-ed, when it goes out of scope.
b := make([]byte, 5)
copy(b, a)

and return the value of b.
As for not able to print the address directly, a slice is implemented internally as a struct holding a pointer to the first element of the slice, the length and the capacity. When we create a sub slice, it still refers to the same underlying array as the original slice, but with a different starting point, length, and possibly capacity.
There is no direct way to get the address of the start of the sub-slice, unless you use unsafe pointer calls.
